# Why does keras model predicts all as ones if used with one-hot labels and categorical_crossentropy amnd softmax output

Tags: python, keras, tf.keras, softmax

I have a simple tf.keras model:

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(9824,))
dense = layers.Dense(512, activation=keras.activations.relu, kernel_initializer=init)
x = dense(inputs)
x = layers.Dense(512, activation=keras.activations.relu)(x)
outputs = layers.Dense(3, activation=keras.activations.softmax)(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
```

When I compile it with sparse categorical crossentropy and actual labels it works as expected.
But when I tried to one-hot encode the labels (with `tf.keras.utils.to_categorical`) and use categorical_crossentropy (so I could use recall and precision as metrics during training), the model predicts everything as ones:

```
>>>print(predictions)
[[1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 ...
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]
 [1. 1. 1.]]
```

If I understand correctly, softmax activation in the output layer should cause the output to be in range (0,1) and sum to 1.
So, **how is it possible that the class predictions are all 1?** I was searching for an answer for hours but to no avail.

### **EDIT**

Here is a minimalistic [example](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Uq7VgYNDftDWJBHxRYzezzhEJdydicKh?usp=sharing).

I forgot to mention that I use scikeras package. Based on examples in the [documentation](https://www.adriangb.com/scikeras/stable/notebooks/Basic_Usage.html#2.2-Definition-of-the-Keras-classification-Model), I assume the model is compiled implicitly. Here is the classifier constructor:

```
clf = KerasClassifier(
    model=keras_model_target,
    loss=SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
    name="model_target",
    optimizer=Adam(),
    init=GlorotUniform(),
    metrics=[SparseCategoricalAccuracy()],
    epochs=5,
    batch_size=128
)
```

I fit the model with

```
result = clf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

and predict with:

```
predictions = clf.predict(x)
```

Comment: why is your last layer build to produce 2 output and your predictions have 3 columns ?

Comment: I copied the wrong code sample as I have two almost identical models with the only difference in # of classes. It should be correct now.

Comment: ok, and how do you obtain the predictions array ?

Comment: Predictions contain the return value of the predict method of the Keras model.

Comment: That is really strange - can you show us the compile and predict parts also?

Comment: Hi, I think this may be a bug in SciKeras! I opened [#299](https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras/pull/229) that should fix and will release SciKeras v0.3.1. I also made a copy of your Colab that works using this branch ([here](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1Ut1yXwPTTEGKEVk8WgOFTZDBGgqTv7n2?authuser=1#scrollTo=xyd9EAW-chrR)). Can you try with SciKeras v0.3.1? Thanks and sorry for any headaches this may have caused!

Comment: Thank you for a quick fix. I haven't tried the new release yet, but I will tomorrow.

Comment: Hi, just checking if you were able to test the new release? I want to make sure I don't leave a bug out in the wild  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @LoveToCode, sorry I did not respond for so long. I tried it with the v0.3.3 and the problem with all predictions being 1 is fixed.

Comment: awesome! I will write that into an answer and you can accept so it gets recorded. Thank you for finding this bug and testing it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in SciKeras that was fixed with the v0.3.1 release. Updating to the latest version should fix the issue.

As for the bug itself, it was due to how we were indexing numpy arrays, see [this diff](https://github.com/adriangb/scikeras/pull/229/files#diff-5d693d5e65da5f017da142d0f3605a90c39ef4128ba9d1bd45577d4e877efbdd) for details.